# Como enviar un mensaje a una cuenta gmail desde DJango

Tags: html, django, bootstrap

Veran, he creado una vista con la cual puede una persona enviar un mensaje a una dirección de correo electronico.
Ya la tengo lista, pero hay un par de fallos:
El primero, aunque algunos factores, como a que dirección de correo se debe enviar el mensaje, estan predeterminados, el formulario igualmente me pide que los indique. Ademas, al intentar enviar el mensaje, me sale un mensaje de error: *No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión*

Codigo del settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Codigo del form:

```
class correo(forms.Form):
    origen=forms.CharField()
    asunto=forms.CharField(required=True)
    destino=forms.EmailField()
    contenido=forms.CharField(max_length=999, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Codigo del view:

```
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datos=form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                "<html><body>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</body></html>", # El usuario escribe el mensaje.
                datos['asunto'],
                'danielpareja1992@gmail.com', # El destino.
                [datos['contenido']],
                fail_silently=False,
                )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

Codigo del HTML:

```
{% load bootstrap %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Enviando un mensaje al administrador</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'maquillar.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'metodos.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center text-muted">Formulario de Contacto</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ forma|bootstrap }}
            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edito: Este es el nuevo codigo HTML.

```
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datos=form.cleaned_data
            email=EmailMessage('title','body', to=['pajaritosami88@gmail.com'])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

El problema es que me pone que el email de origen tambien se llama "pajaritosami88@gmail.com", incluso aunque el usuario tenga otro email. ¿Como indico el nombre del email que envio el mensaje?

Comment: Yo tengo dos preguntas: 1. ¿por qué si la dirección de destino es predeterminada, la solicitas en tu formulario? Es muy raro. 2. ¿Intentas mandar correos a gmail desde `localhost`? No vas a poder, te presento a [SPF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

Comment: Acabo de recordar esta configuración en las cuentas de Google.

Comment: @toledano ¿Y que parte del codigo cambio para dejar de pedir la dirección de destino?

Comment: En la clase del formulario, ahi la veo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar correos desde django debes:

Establecer la configuración en settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ALGO@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**************'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Para que google permita enviar mails desde esta dirección vas a tener que
acceder a tu cuenta > Acceso y Seguridad > Opción Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras: ACTIVADA

Después solo te quedara ir a tus vistas y:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
email.send()
```

en tu view:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
class contacto(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=correo()
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=correo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datos=form.cleaned_data

            email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
            email.send()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'email.html',{'forma':form})
```

Comment: La parte del settings la entiendo (aunque, ¿los '*' de la contraseña son así o indica que ponga mi propia contraseña?), aunque no la del view. Se como hacer la parte de la importación, pero, ¿el codigo "email" se tiene que poner en algun metodo o como? A parte, ¿conservo el form o lo elimino?

Comment: Si, los *** son para que pongas tu propio pass. (Recuerda configurarlo en google si no no te dejará enviar.)
Actualizo el post con las modificaciones de tu view.

Comment: Esto de la contraseña me es extraño. ¿Si, por ejemplo, tuviese de contraseña de gmail "gatitos", tendria que escribir esta palabra en la variable EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD?

Comment: Aparte, hice los cambios en el codigo que indicaste, saliendome este mensaje de error al intentar enviar este mensaje de error: **local variable 'email' referenced before assignment**.

Comment: No entiendo que te causa confusión del pasword del settings. solo debes poner tu pasword. El error del que hablas, quiere decir que la linea "email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=['destino@gmail.com'])" no esta. o no esta bien

Comment: ¡Lo que temía! No podría darle el código de este proyecto a nadie, pues al verme obligado a entregar mi contraseña de gmail para que esto funcione, pondría la seguridad de mi cuenta en compromiso. **Ya he conseguido enviar el mensaje, pero ahora necesito saber como indicar quien envió el mensaje.**

Comment: Pero quitando esto, ya he conseguido que el programa eche a funcionar. Veo que el mensaje va a nombre de mi mismo. Los usuarios tienen que poner su email, por lo que a ver como se hace para indicar el email del usuario.

Comment: Si tu pregunta fue contestada, cierra esta aceptando una respuesta valida. Si el proceso te ha generado mas dudas abre otra pregunta.

Comment: Vale, dare por cerrado este chat. Tengo aun unas dudas, pero para ello he abierto otra pregunta.